# Why the index.html in dist built from Angular does not work in docker?

Tags: angular, docker

Using Python Flask as back-end and Angular 6 as front-end.

I am following the structure from here: https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker

This is the structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── main.py
│   └── static
│       └── index.html
└── Dockerfile
```

And the tree view of `dist` generated by Angular

```
.
├──3rdpartylicenses.txt
├──favicon.ico
├──index.html
├──main.814148b8a52c3996d8f6.js
├──polyfills.c72d3210425a88b28b6d.js
├──runtime.6afe30102d8fe7337431.js
└──styles.914f038ddd792d8e3589.css
```

What I do is:

1. `ng build --prod`
2. move all files generated by Angular in `dist` folder to `static` in the structure.
3. `docker build -t myimage .`
4. `docker run -d --rm --name mycontainer -p 80:80 myimage`

And I run in my browser on `0.0.0.0`.

What I get is:

[image]

This is weird since if I use simple `index.html` file, like only hello world in that, it works great. But with Angular-built stuff, it gives me 500 internal server error. Seems there is a problem when I `ng build --prod`. Can someone tell me what happens?

I have read some articles talking about the problem might be on `<base href="/">` in `index.html`. I have tried to change it to `<base href="/static/">` and `<base href="/app/static/">`. However, I did not get lucky. Really need help here. Thank you!

BTW, the website is fine when I `ng serve` it. So it probably is not about a bug in the code.

Comment: Give us a tree view of generated files `ng build --prod`

Comment: @RitwickDey Sorry for the late update. Please see the update. Thank you. :)